# Bugzilla CGI not working under Apache on Windows 7

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, windows-7, cgi, bugzilla

I am trying to install Bugzilla on my Windows 7 machine. I have only been able to get the apache,mysql,perl stack operational by installing XAMPP. Apache works well for php, and mysql seems quite happy, yet I can't get apache to execute cgi for bugzilla.

When I browse to 'http://localhost/bugzilla/', I get the following error:

```
couldn't create child process: 720002: index.cgi
```

I found this page when googling the error, https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install, but all the settings it recommends adding to or uncommenting in apache's httpd.conf are already present. What else can I do?

Comment: Do you have the cgi files associated with perl? Try double click one. Also, please post the first line of index.cgi.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the script checksetup.pl, what it say ?

These two links could be useful read for you :

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:FAQ:Bugzilla_and_Win32 
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install#Configure_CGI

Comment: Hehe, every time I run that script it says something different. When I posted my question though, it reported a DB error. Googling that error suggested I could clear the 'check_db' setting to proceed. The db is alive and well though, and the connection settings in localconfig are correct.